# Windows Azure: Register Application to Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

Following is the scenario which works differently in windows azure,

**Scenario 1:**

1. Create web app from visual studio using Azure AD authentication setup.
2. Application works fine. Authentication is successful.

**Scenario 2**

1. Manually add application to Azure Active directory
2. Update the configuration related to new application register in Active directory and try to authenticate the application.

In the Scenario 2, Getting error that **"Application with identifier XXXX not found in the directory XXXXX"**

Comment: Is your intent to register a single tenant or multi-tenant application? Which portal did you use to register the app in scenario 2? What configuration changes did you make? What code are you using to "authenticate the application"? What is the user account you used to sign-in? What is the full error message (there shouldn't be anything to hide in the error message)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it should be that either you using the incorrect application id or the tenant. Please ensure the app you config in the project is on the tenant you were using.

Microsoft also provides lots of code sample to help developer get started with developing Azure AD. You may refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-code-samples/) which contains the detail steps for register and config apps manually.